# Chevron icons should behave separately on hovering dropdown menus in react js

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, antd

I am facing this problem to show the chevron icon behavior separately on mouseover on each dropdown menu. I mean each chevron icon does **UP** and **DOWN WHEN I'll hover on it separately.**

What is I want to hover the chevron icon for each dropdown menu separately so that when I hover on the menu label it does the behavior only once and should not affect other menu labels I tried to implement logic to achieve this: [chevron icon on hovering](https://icecreamapps.com/v/cvkm3tc) but, still couldn't get it.

So far, I did like this where all chevron icons are behaving on every menu: [working code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/change-icon-on-hovering-drop-down-menus-forked-l1guqg?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js) What I'm missing here ??

Is there any way in reactjs to get the chevron icon effect separately for each menu on mouse hover ??

Please help me with this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching & googling, I found a way that was silly strange for me and maybe for you, that instead of icons I also could use
svg adding this `group and group-hover:-rotate(-180)` in SVG's className
and this works fine as expected!

```
<a onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                  <Space
                    className="relative group ml-10 cursor-pointer hover:text-purple-500 text-[16px]"
                  >
                    {item.menu}
                    <span>
                      <svg
                        className="fill-current stroke-0 stroke-slate-600  h-3.5 w-3.5 transform group-hover:-rotate-180
    transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                      >
                        <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" />
         </svg>
      </span>
     </Space>
</a>
```